# Linux cp command is not silent

Tags: cp

I know with a -f cp should be silent but it's not!
I do

```
cp -rf Functional Functionalssssssss
```

and if Functional does not exist, it says
cannot stat 'Functional'...
but I just don't want to see the error message!! I want to handle them myself

Comment: --force option shouldnt be silent. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html to make silent the command just redirect output to  /dev/null

Answer (score 8):

The `cannot stat...` output is actually being send to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  For the specific example you provide in the question, the following will suppress the error output by redirecting `stderr` to `/dev/null`:

```
cp -rf Functional Functionalssssssss 2>/dev/null
```

As well, at least for the version of `cp` on my Debian Linux server, `-f` is not a universal 'silence' flag. It's instead a synonym for `--force`, meaning that `cp` will silently obliterate any existing destination file before copying.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked!! I actually wrongly understoud -f, I though it was for silent!!

Comment: @Cher And I thought 'F' was used to Pay respects. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bash or sh(posix standard), `[ -f file ] && cp file target`
is what you want.

This one will check if the file exists and copy it. Say goodbye to errors.

Comment: thank you for the answer. This works, but I still don't get why I can't silent the whole command?

Comment: This isn't a very good solution. Even if the source file is present, the copy operation could fail for various reasons.

Comment: OP also used `-r` indicating the source may very well be a directory, not a file as tested by `[ -f ... ]`.

Comment: This has an inherent race condition: the file might be deleted *in between* the test and the `cp`.  It probably doesn't matter in this case but similar constructs can and have produced catastrophic security holes and other bugs.